# How to pay multiple invoice in 1 payment QUICKBOOKS API

Tags: php, api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Good Day!

I am currently working on a QUICKBOOKS API payment and is using their DevKit https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php its working just fine, I can retrieve invoices and pay them individually. Now, I want to create a functionality that can pay multiple invoices in 1 payment. What I could think right now is doing a loop until all selected invoices gets paid individually but I guess its not the correct approach..

this is the code I got from the DevKit

```
$PaymentService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Payment();

// Create payment object
$Payment = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Payment();

$Payment->setPaymentRefNum('WEB123');
$Payment->setTxnDate('2014-02-11');
$Payment->setTotalAmt(10);

// Create line for payment (this details what it's applied to)
$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setAmount(10);

// The line has a LinkedTxn node which links to the actual invoice
$LinkedTxn = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_LinkedTxn();
$LinkedTxn->setTxnId('{-84}');
$LinkedTxn->setTxnType('Invoice');

$Line->setLinkedTxn($LinkedTxn);

$Payment->addLine($Line);

$Payment->setCustomerRef('{-67}');

// Send payment to QBO 
if ($resp = $PaymentService->add($Context, $realm, $Payment))
{
    print('Our new Payment ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
}
else
{
    print($PaymentService->lastError());
}
```

If I put them inside a loop, I am sure they will all get paid and also it will create multiple payments as well.

Is there any other much better ways to do this? please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work with this code

```
$c = 0;
foreach ($invoice_ids as $i) {
    $Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
    $Line->setAmount($i_line_amount[$c]); //amount per line
    $LinkedTxn = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_LinkedTxn();
    $LinkedTxn->setTxnId($i);
    $LinkedTxn->setTxnType('Invoice');
    $Line->setLinkedTxn($LinkedTxn);
    $Payment->addLine($Line);
    $c++;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this stuff more than one time:

```
// The line has a LinkedTxn node which links to the actual invoice
$LinkedTxn = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_LinkedTxn();
$LinkedTxn->setTxnId('{-84}');
$LinkedTxn->setTxnType('Invoice');

$Line->setLinkedTxn($LinkedTxn);

$Payment->addLine($Line);
```

For example:

```
foreach ($invoices as $invoice_id)
{
    // The line has a LinkedTxn node which links to the actual invoice
    $LinkedTxn = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_LinkedTxn();
    $LinkedTxn->setTxnId($invoice_id);
    $LinkedTxn->setTxnType('Invoice');

    $Line->setLinkedTxn($LinkedTxn);

    $Payment->addLine($Line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Sir.. shouldnt I inlcude the "$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setAmount(10);" to set the amount per line?